# F# SEPA XML Serialization throws an exception

Tags: xml, serialization, .net-core, f#

I am creating a converter to SEPA XML in F# using the .NET XML Serializer:

```xml
[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="InitgPty", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type InitiatingParty = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Nm", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Name: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="GrpHdr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type GroupHeader = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="MsgId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    MessageId: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CreDtTm", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    CreationDateTime: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="NbOfTxs", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    TransactionCount: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CtrlSum", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    ControlSum: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="InitgPty", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    InitiatingParty: InitiatingParty
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="SvcLvl", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type ServiceLevel = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Cd", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Code: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtTpInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type PaymentTypeInformation = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="SvcLvl", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    ServiceLevel: ServiceLevel
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="Dbtr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type Debtor = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Nm", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Name: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="Id", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type Id = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="IBAN", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Iban: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="DbtrAcct", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type DebtorAccount = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Id", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Id: Id
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Ccy", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Currency: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="FinInstnId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type FinancialInstitutionId = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="BIC", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Bic: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="DbtrAgt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type DebtorAgent = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="FinInstnId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    FinancialInstitutionId: FinancialInstitutionId
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type PaymentIdentification = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="EndToEndId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    EndToEndId: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="InstdAmt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type InstructedAmount = {
    [<XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Ccy")>]
    Currency: string
    [<XmlText>]
    Text: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="Amt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type Amount = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="InstdAmt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    InstructedAmount: InstructedAmount
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="CdtrAgt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type CreditorAgent = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="FinInstnId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    FinancialInstitutionId: FinancialInstitutionId
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="Cdtr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type Creditor = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Nm", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Name: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="CdtrAcct", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type CreditorAccount = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Id", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Id: Id
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="RmtInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type RemittanceInformation = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Ustrd", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Unstructured: string
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type CreditTransferTransactionInformation = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentIdentification: PaymentIdentification

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Amt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Amount: Amount

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtrAgt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    CreditorAgent: CreditorAgent

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Cdtr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Creditor: Creditor

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtrAcct", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    CreditorAccount: CreditorAccount

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="RmtInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    RemittanceInformation: RemittanceInformation
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type PaymentInformation = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtInfId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentInformationId: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtMtd", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentMethod: string 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="NbOfTxs", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    TransactionCount: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CtrlSum", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    ControlSum: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtTpInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentTypeInformation: PaymentTypeInformation 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="ReqdExctnDt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    RequestedExecutionDate: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Dbtr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Debtor: Debtor 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="DbtrAcct", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    DebtorAccount: DebtorAccount

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="DbtrAgt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    DebtorAgent: DebtorAgent 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="ChrgBr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    ChargeBearer: string 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    CreditTransferTransactionInformation: List<CreditTransferTransactionInformation>  
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="CstmrCdtTrfInitn", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type CustomerCreditTransferInitialization = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="GrpHdr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    GroupHeader: GroupHeader 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentInformation: PaymentInformation 
}

[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="Document", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type Document = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CstmrCdtTrfInitn", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    CustomerCreditTransferInitialization: CustomerCreditTransferInitialization 

    [<XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")>]
    Xsi: string 

    [<XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")>]
    Xmlns: string
}
```

When using the serializer it crash:

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof<Document>)
    return 0
```

The exception I have:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Program.Document'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'CustomerCreditTransferInitialization'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Program.CustomerCreditTransferInitialization'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'PaymentInformation'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Program.PaymentInformation'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'CreditTransferTransactionInformation'. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel parent, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElement(TypeModel model, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, RecursionLimiter limiter)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
   at Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\SepaConversion\SepaConversion\Program.fs:line 221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue:

`List<Whatever>` does not work for the serialization of a collection of elements in :

```ml
[<CLIMutable>]
[<XmlRoot(ElementName="PmtInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
type PaymentInformation = {
    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtInfId", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentInformationId: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtMtd", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentMethod: string 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="NbOfTxs", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    TransactionCount: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CtrlSum", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    ControlSum: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="PmtTpInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    PaymentTypeInformation: PaymentTypeInformation 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="ReqdExctnDt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    RequestedExecutionDate: string

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="Dbtr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    Debtor: Debtor 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="DbtrAcct", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    DebtorAccount: DebtorAccount

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="DbtrAgt", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    DebtorAgent: DebtorAgent 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="ChrgBr", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    ChargeBearer: string 

    [<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
    CreditTransferTransactionInformation: List<CreditTransferTransactionInformation>  
}
```

In particular:

```ml
[<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
CreditTransferTransactionInformation: List<CreditTransferTransactionInformation>
```

Which needed to be converted to an actual array:

```ml
[<XmlElement(ElementName="CdtTrfTxInf", Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03")>]
CreditTransferTransactionInformation: CreditTransferTransactionInformation[]
```

Then it works like a charm!